# Is there a way to access the Junit configuration parameter from the test

Tags: java, kotlin, junit, junit5

I am setting some properties as below when I launch the Junit Tests programmatically.

```
    LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder
            .request()
            .selectors(selectMethod("com.example#testMethod()"))
            .configurationParameter("My_Param","Hello")
            .build()
```

Is there a way to access `My_Param` from the test method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the `ExtensionContext.getConfigurationParameter()` method.

From JUnit 5.1.0 release notes:

> Extensions for JUnit Jupiter can now access JUnit Platform configuration parameters at runtime via the new getConfigurationParameter(String key) method in the ExtensionContext API.

The obvious way to access the `ExtensionContext` would be to implement an extension.

An alternative would be to implement one of the lifecycle callbacks directly in the test:

```java
public class YourTest implements BeforeEachCallback {
  @Override
  public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
  }
}
```

Comment: blue_man I tried this but my code is visiting beforeEach method. did you find any solution.